How did borrowings from Latin and French affect verb conjugation in English?
More specifically, I'm trying to learn how verbs in Old English were influenced by Latin and French. For example, by means of changes in verb conjugation, if they occurred at all. Please, provide examples.

Were they affected? What do you mean by "noun inflection and verbs were affected"? And what research have you done yourself?

Compare the noun system of Old English with that of middle/early modern English. One is much closer to German, the other to French. I doubt Latin had much direct influence except for vocabulary, a few incorrect plurals like octopi, and weird things like the prohibition on splitting infinitives.

@PaulTanenbaum By noun inflections I mean adding a suffix to a noun, for example, to form a plural noun.  Did verb conjugation in Old English receive any influence from French at all?

You also need to think about the impact of Norse on the simplification of Old English (and of Norman French).

Noun inflections: yes, for example some plurals (oxen -> oxes), but the case system disappeared nearly completely, so it is probably hard to distinguish which changes were influenced by French.  Verb inflections not so much.

Do you not believe that any real Answer would take a whole text-book, at least?
By the way, I suggest it's your job, not anyone else's, to please provide examples. Who thinks the mistake is mine, please say so… and preferably also, say why!

Verbs in Old Saxon are all inflected for person and are divided into strong and weak verbs.
From Wiki:

Strong verbs indicate tense by a change in the quality of a vowel, while weak verbs indicate tense by the addition of an ending.

Strong verbs remained strong verbs. Know-> knew-> have known; Drink -> drank -> have drunk, etc.
The personal inflections except the third person singular "s" have all disappeared in all verbs (the 2nd person singular "-est" being the latest to go - although that went because its pronoun went.)
Weak verbs remained weak verbs .
From Wiki:

The past and past-participle forms of weak verbs are formed with a (t or d) added to the end of the stem. Some modern English examples of this are love, loved or look, looked.

From Wiki:

As English came into contact with non-Germanic languages, it invariably borrowed useful verbs which lacked established stem-change patterns. Rather than inventing and standardizing new classes or learning foreign conjugations, English speakers simply applied the weak ending to the foreign bases. The same process also happened with Dutch, German and occurs in modern Germanic languages.


There is much more to this subject than what I can gather, but I'll mention one point in the beginning of it (which I can verify, and which shows that it is a complex study).
The influence of latin and French is felt differently for certain suffixes from Latin and French origin. Certain suffixes from French origin may almost exclusively impinge on vocabulary with French and Latin roots; this is the case for the very common suffix "-ion" (French ion, Latin -ion, -io).  Other suffixes inherited from French  may impinge on the word formation of words with Anglo-Saxon roots; this is the case for the rather common suffix "-ment" (French "-ment").
A complete examination  for "-ion" shows that only the following words with an Anglo-Saxon root have this suffix. (There will probably be a few more such words, I used a small size dictionary (56 000 entries).)

bowdlerisation,
flirtation,
starvation,
westernization,
botheration

In the case of "-ment", however, a search only from a to e (included), yields numerous words with a root in Anglo-Saxon or Middle English.

ailment,
amazement,
bafflement,
bedazzlement,
bedevilment,
befuddlement,
belittlement,
bereavement,
betterment,
bewilderment,
bewitchment,
catchment,
devilment,
disembodiment,
disembowelment,
disentanglement,
disgruntlement,
elopement,
embitterment,
embodiment,
endearment,
enlightenment,
enlivenment,
enmeshment,
enshrinement,
ensnarement,
enthralment


Malheureusement, this no longer answers the question because the asker has updated his question to restrict the matter to the verb’s inflectional morphology, not merely its derivational morphology.
